# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.view.GestureDetector

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this error when trying to initialize a horizontal scroll view class:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.view.GestureDetector

private synchronized void initView() {
        mLeftViewIndex = -1;
        mRightViewIndex = 0;
        mDisplayOffset = 0;
        mCurrentX = 0;
        mNextX = 0;
        mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }
```

the error is being traced back to this line:

```
mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
```

mGesture is a private GestureDetector:

```
private GestureDetector mGesture;
```

[image: my UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need it when in edit mode anyway, so do as the tip says:

```
private synchronized void initView() {
    mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    mRightViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentX = 0;
    mNextX = 0;
    mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (!this.isInEditMode()) {
        mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
        mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
    }
}
```

And then check for mGesture and mCcroller being null in the code before using.