# Android onPostExecute not updating Main UI ArrayWheelAdapter WheelView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I am currently trying to populate my WheelView from within the onPostExecute method inside my AsyncTask inner class.

The following code works just like it should if put directly into the onCreate() method, however when inside of the onPostExecute() method the wheel on the screen displays nothing.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_reg);
    ctx = getApplicationContext();

    // text1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.r1);
    wheel = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.p1);
    CarAsync carAsync = new CarAsync(this);
    carAsync.execute();

String[] sss = new String[]{"Hi"};
wheel.setViewAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(ctx, sss));
wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);

}
```

Here is the onPostExecute() method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Car> cars) {
   String[] sss = new String[]{"Hi"};
   wheel.setViewAdapter(new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(ctx, sss));
   wheel.setVisibleItems(2);
   wheel.setCurrentItem(0);
   wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
   wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hitting!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is the Layout XML

```
<kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
android:id="@+id/p1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

**wheel** is declared as a private class level field. I know that the onPostExecute method is being reached. I have set break points and also inserted a toast.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ref: http://w2davids.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/advanced-android-ui-wheelpicker/

**Log error:**
Error

```
Mon Oct 07 18:29:39 PDT 2013
kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView failed to instantiate.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.view.GestureDetector
    at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelScroller.<init>(WheelScroller.java:86)
    at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.initData(WheelView.java:131)
    at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.<init>(WheelView.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateActivated(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:743)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.activated(CommonXmlEditor.java:416)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.LayoutWindowCoordinator.partActivated(LayoutWindowCoordinator.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService$6.run(PartService.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartService.partActivated(PartService.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4462)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.firePartActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:4460)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$16(WorkbenchPage.java:4440)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$2.run(PartServiceImpl.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$ActivationJob.run(StackRenderer.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3946)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: what errors are you getting/or warnings, post your log

Comment: waht do you have on line 86, this could be the problem `ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.view.GestureDetector at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelScroller.(WheelScroller.java:86`

Comment: Yes, I have already looked into this line. It does not show any errors. From my own research this error is with respect to the edit mode in eclipse. See: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856497/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-android-view-gestured>

Comment: why didnt it work when you changed `ctx` to `this` ? what was the error then?

Comment: I am not getting errors either way.

Comment: try not executing the code in `onPostExecute()` does it work if you add dummy values in `onCreate` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38758/discussion-between-ilovepjs-and-padawan)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I took a few minutes to get something working. I just edited the supplied wheel-demo project's CitiesAvtivity.java class to use an inner class defined async task. This works.

```
package kankan.wheel.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView;
import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.ArrayWheelAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CitiesActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> cities; 
WheelView city;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.cities_layout);
    cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    cities.add("New York");
    cities.add("Washington");
    cities.add("Chicago");
    cities.add("Atlanta");
    cities.add("Orlando");

    city = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.city);
    city.setVisibleItems(5);
    TestTask task = new TestTask(this);
    task.execute(null);
}

/**
 * Updates the city wheel
 */
private void updateCities(String cities[]) {
    ArrayWheelAdapter<String> adapter =
        new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this, cities);
    adapter.setTextSize(18);
    city.setViewAdapter(adapter);
    city.setCurrentItem(cities.length / 2);        
}


private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    private ProgressDialog wait;

    public TestTask(Context context){
        wait = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        wait.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000); //This is where you actually do what you need to
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cities;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        String[] array = new String[result.size()];
        result.toArray(array);
        updateCities(array);
        wait.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace  is about Eclipse not Android. What happen in Android is, that your `onPostExecute()` is never called. This method is part of AsyncTask and is preceded by a run of `doInBackground()`.

Have a look if you ever enter `onPostExecute()` and if you ever finish `doInBackground()`.